# Solana-test-validator error

Tags: solana-test-validator

➜  ~ solana-test-validator

Notice! No wallet available. `solana airdrop` localnet SOL after creating one

Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Error: failed to start validator: Failed to create ledger at test-ledger: blockstore error

This is the error i am getting when i try to run,a local solana block chain on my machine

Comment: Is your user able to create files in the directory from which you're running `solana-test-validator`? You may need to give some more information about your setup